# use fuse.js in Angular 2 application (typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, fuse.js

I tried to import fuse.js in a angular2 app, but I get an exception (Fuse is not defined). 
I also check definitions file (index.d.ts)  in the package.

my class in typescript is :

```
import 'fuse.js';

export class Myclass{

  /**some code*/

  public mySearchFunction(text, list, Opts){
    let fuseSearch  = new Fuse(list, Opts);
    let fuseResults: any[] = fuseSearch.search(text);
    return fuseResults
  }

}
```

I tried also with

```
import * as Fuse from 'fuse.js';
```

What is the right way to use this library?

Comment: I did an angular + fusejs integration that supports highlighting matches. This post is almost 1 year old, so I guess you already found a solution, but I'm dropping this here in case somebody else need it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-fusejs

Answer (score 4):

The typings were only added to the project 8 days ago. If you look at the latest NPM release from [here](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/tree/v2.5.0) you'll see the typings aren't included.

If you either pull the package from `master` or grab files `package.json` and `index.d.ts`, then you'll be able to use the package with `import * as Fuse from 'fuse.js';`

Looking at the console, I'm still getting error `Cannot find module 'fuse.js'`, but it's working. Not sure what that's all about.

Version 2.6.1 got pushed to NPM yesterday, which supports typings - see [here](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/issues/123)

Comment: it doesn't work for me,  I solved rewriting fuse.js as typescript class. it is a temporary solution.

Comment: Mind posting your class?

Also, an alternate fix until a new version is to pushed to NPM is to add `declare var Fuse: any;` You won't get intellisense but at least it'll stop TS from throwing compilation errors.

Comment: you can find the class [here](https://codepad.co/snippet/HrkAikGa) .  variables have  not correct type but it works. As I said ,  it is  a temp solution

Comment: See also https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/pull/124 with a workaround in its description, @Dag

Comment: With @Dag's [temporary TypeScript class](https://codepad.co/snippet/HrkAikGa) I ran into `Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined` when using it for nested paths (`Fuse.deepValue`). Changing line 102 to use a fat arrow fixes that: `getFn: (obj, path, list) => this.deepValue(obj, path, list),` The workaround from the GitHub issue in my previous comment didn't work for me either; sorry, but I forgot why. The pull request from that same GitHub issue is giving me trouble too. Oh well :-)

Comment: A lot later, I've finally replaced @Dag's workaround with the latest from NPM, and that works fine with `import * as Fuse from 'fuse.js'`. (Minor problems with [reporting circular dependencies in my objects](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/issues/196), but that's unrelated.)